# How to add headers in websocket using autobahn library on android?

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I am using [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) library for websocket on android, I just want to pass some headers while connecting ? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't find any method to send headers from autobahn libs, so I have modified Autobahn library by myself. This is the [Link](https://github.com/bhaumikshukla/AutobahnAndroid) for that lib. 
[Click here](https://github.com/bhaumikshukla/AutobahnAndroid/tree/master/Demo/SimplePubSub) for android pub-sub sample application implementation using this updated lib.

Comment: So would you mind sharing the syntax to add the headers before the handshake? I could not quite find that in your example. Thanks!